# how to denormalize the image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, normalization, dwt

I am working on a project where i have to first normalize the image i.e convert the pixel range of my image from 16-235 (as it is only luminance component of the image , pixel values are always defined in the range 16-235) to 0 - 1 then i perform dwt and idwt on the image after the processing i want to again maps these pixels values from 0 - 1 to 16 - 235. ie if the pixel value is 1 value then it should be stored in the image matrix as 235.
for which i tried the following matlab code ,this code works perfectly fine when i denormalize the image immediately after normalization , but output becomes complete white if i use this code after performing dwt and idwt.

```
for j = 1:1:361
    for k=1:1:361                   %dimensions of my matrix
        if(distorted1(j,k)~=0)
            temp=distorted1(j,k);
            temp1=temp/0.0045;

            distorted1(j,k)=int8(temp1)+1;
        end
    end
end
imshow(distorted1);
```

Comment: You should visualize the image `imshow(distorted1,[])` rather than `imshow(distorted1)`. Plain old `imshow` without the `[]` will saturate `double` values to white if they go above the maximum value of `1.0`.

Answer (score 3):

it seems like the result of your `idwt` is of type `double` ( or `single` ) and not `int` anymore. convert to `uint8` and then `imshow` it.

Trying to `imshow` an image of type `double`/`single` will saturate all pixels with values larger than 1.0 (rather than 255 for images of type `int`).